# parameter use in R

Tags: r, function, parameters

```
scorekm <- function(km, x1,x2,x3,x4) {
    data<-matrix(c(x1,x2,x3,x4),nrow=1)
    k <- nrow(km$centers)
    n <- nrow(data)
    d <- as.matrix(dist(rbind(km$centers, data)))[-(1:k),1:k]
    d <- matrix(d,nrow=1)
    out <- apply(d, 1, which.min)
    return(out)
}
```

This is my original function. Now there are several parameters (not just 4, maybe 8, 12,...), and every 4 as a unit. Should I use for loop? In the for loop, how can I reach the parameter?and how do I know how many there are?

```
 scorekm <- function(km,x...){}
```

Function should be like this.

```
km<-kmeans(iris,3)
scorekm<-
function(km, x,...)
{
result=NULL
for(i in 1:nargs()-1)
{
data<-matrix(c(args[[i+1]],args[[i+2]],args[[i+3]],args[[i+4]]),nrow=1)
k <- nrow(km$centers)
d <- as.matrix(dist(rbind(km$centers, data)))[-(1:k),1:k]
d <- matrix(d,nrow=1)
out <- apply(d, 1, which.min)
result<-cbind(out,result)
i<-i+4
}
return(result)}
```

Comment: scorekm<-
function(km, x,...)
{}   It should be like this.

Comment: Sorry, I have already saved my changes.

Comment: Your question is still kind of unclear. What are you trying to do with  x1, x2, x3, etc.? Do you want to make a matrix out of them, regardless of how many there are?

Comment: Every 4 parameters is a unit.They are used as the parameters for kmeans. And now the function has several parameters ,not just 4,maybe 8.

Comment: I have saved my changes again.It should be like this.But there are some problems with my code.I don't know what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

I would collect all the variables through `...` like so:

```
scorekm <- function(km, x, ...) {
  x.args <- list(...)
  out <- do.call("cbind", x.args)
  out
}
```

Notice that by naming your argument, you're giving it a column name "as you go".

```
> scorekm(km = 1, x = 2, x1 = runif(3), column2 = runif(3), variable3 = runif(3))
            x1    column2 variable3
[1,] 0.2106436 0.07142857 0.6466394
[2,] 0.3684540 0.16306419 0.9937268
[3,] 0.5230319 0.66318683 0.3020110
```